# Contraction mapping on the compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

Let $E$ be a compact metric space with metric $\rho$, and $f\colon E \to E$ be such that $\rho(f(x), f(y)) < \rho(x, y)$. The task is to prove that $f$ has a unique fixed-point and to find out whether $f$ is a the contraction mapping?

I understand how to prove existence and uniqueness of the fixed point, but have struggled with the last part of the question.

Please, give me hint on this :)

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^2/2$ on $E=[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis $$\tag0 \rho(f(x),f(y))<\rho(x,y),\ \ \ x\ne y$$ is that $f$ is "pointwise" contractive, but the definition of contraction requires a uniform bound, i.e. $$\tag1 \rho(f(x),f(y))<\delta\,\rho(x,y)$$ for some $\delta\in(0,1)$ and all $x,y$.

If you consider $f(x)=x^2/2$, $E=[0,1]$ there is no $c<1$ with $$\frac{|x^2-y^2|}2\leq c\,|x-y|$$ for all $x,y\in [0,1]$. The quotient $$\frac{\left|\frac{x^2-y^2}2\right|}{|x-y|}=\frac{|x+y|}2,$$   can be made arbitrarily close to $1$, but it will only be $1$ when $x=y$, which of course is does not fit in the hypothesis.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks.